# Is there a way to avoid using ._1 in scala slick queries?

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I have the following query in scala:

```
val query = for {
      (table1, table2) <- Customer leftJoin Transaction on (_.custID === _.custID) 
      if table1.name === "ABCD"          
    } yield (table1.name, table2.date)
```

When I use `query` i have to use `query._1` or `query._2` for `name` and `date` respectively. Is the a way to use something of this kind: `query.name`, `query.date`

Comment: Why don't you use a `case class Query(name: String, date: Date)` instead of a generic tuple?

Comment: Thank you, case class will solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your for expression is returning a tuple, and tuples can be easily deconstructed using pattern matching (nothing Slick-specific here) :

```
val (foo, bar) = ("foo", "bar") // foo="foo", bar="bar"
```

You should be able to do the same with the tuple returned by the Slick query :

```
val (name, date) =
  for {
    (table1, table2) <- Customer leftJoin Transaction on (_.custID === _.custID)
    if table1.name === "ABCD"          
  } yield (table1.name, table2.date)
```

Comment: The expression is not returning a tuple. It returns a query which will return a list of tuples -> expression.list will return a list of tuples.

Comment: It makes sense, but then, your exemple of using `query._1` or  `query._2` shouldn't work either? That being said, on a list of tuples, you can use something like `myList map { case (name, date) => /* do somehting */}`; or, in your for expression, instead of yielding a tuple, you could yield a case class. I will edit my answer as soon as I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching for that issue

```
val (name, date) = for {...}
```

so when the left side matches the right side the variables will get the values

Example for a tuple:

```
val (a,b) = (1,2)
scala> val (a,b) = (1,2)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
```